# Symfony Validating Froms

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I have a symfony form. Now, I'm planning to implement validation for which I've written a validation.yml file as follows

```
Core\AppBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        name:
            - Length:
                min: 5
                max: 255
                minMessage: "Your name should be at least {{ limit }} characters"
                maxMessage: "Your name cannot be more than {{ limit }} characters"
```

Now symfony validates with the given constraints when I use the following snippet in my Action

```
$validator = $this->get('validator');
$errors = $validator->validate($user);
```

However, If I use

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

}

return $response;
```

The validation is not done.

But according to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-and-forms) article, Synfony uses internally the validator service and additionally converts ConstraintViolationList objects into FieldErrors which comes in really handy for my purpose.

What might be the mistake in my workflow ?

EDIT1:

```
$form = $this->createForm(new RegType(), $reg);
```

and $reg is an object which contains the entity User as a variable.

Comment: do you call ``$form->handleRequest($request)`` before ``$form->isValid()``?

Comment: Yes, I did. btw my variable `$form = $this->createForm(new RegType(), $reg);` and $reg is an object which contains the entity User as a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your data_class set as Core\AppBundle\Entity\User in your default options for RegType?  That is how the form determines if it needs to do additional validation.

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Core\AppBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}
```

Comment: RegType has buildForm function with `$builder->add('user', new UserType()) ` and few other fields 

and UserType has the above setDefaultOptions function with data_class set as ..\User

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right path. Solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to have missed the handle request.

```
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // build the form ...

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(
            'admin_post_show',
            array('id' => $post->getId())
        ));
    }

    // render the template
}
```

Have a look at the [symfony best pratices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html)

Comment: There is a call to the handleRequest function. I got the form working after which I started writing validation constraints